# Rendering Formik Field outside Formik form

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik

We have our own input components (like `Checkbox`, `Textbox`, or even `CurrencyInput` component)

We are now using [Formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik). So we **replaced** all `<input...` with `<Field...` in our components, eg.

```
const Checkbox = (props) => {
  ...
  return (
    <div className={myClass1}>
      <Field type='checkbox' name={props.name} className={myClass2} ... />
      <label ...>{props.label}</label>
    </div>
  )
};
```

Now the problem is, we can't have a **standalone** `Checkbox` outside a form anymore (eg. for an on-screen-only option). It will throw:

> this.props.formik.registerField is not a function

We feel this is a **dealbreaker**. But before we ditch Formik and write our own form validation logics, I wonder if anyone else are having this dependency issue.

Is there really no way of rendering Formik `Field` outside `Formik`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Field` component is what connects a form field to the Formik state. It uses context under the hood; `Formik` is the context provider and `Field` is the context consumer. `Field` is tied to `Formik` and has no use outside of it. For your use case where you want to render form fields that are sometimes connected to Formik and sometimes not, I would export two different components:

1. The base Checkbox component that has nothing to do with Formik. It should just use a normal input
2. A Field wrapper around that Checkbox component

While the `Field` component can take a `type`, causing it to render the corresponding input, it [can also take a render prop](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field#field-render-props) to render whatever you want, and it is passed all of the state Formik manages for that field.

For example, your Checkbox and CheckboxField components could looks something like this:

```
const Checkbox = (props) => {
  ...
  return (
    <div className={myClass1}>
      <input type='checkbox' checked={props.checked} onChange={props.onChange} />
      <label ...>{props.label}</label>
    </div>
  )
};

const CheckboxField = (props) => {
  return (
    <Field name={props.name}>
      {(field) => <Checkbox label={props.label} {...field} />}
    </Field>
  )
}
```

Now you use have two components that render exactly the same, but one is meant to be used within a Formik form (`CheckboxField`) and the other can be used anywhere (`Checkbox`).